# Editing a question caused the creation of a new one instead

Tags: bug, status-norepro, questions, edits

I've created a post on Stack Overflow here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404766/how-to-make-oc4j-dont-print-the-stacktrace

And then I edited it, but I found that it createed a brand new post!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404763/how-to-make-oc4j-dont-print-the-stacktrace

I think this is an issue.

Comment: How did you edit it? If you used the browser's back button then I can see this happening.

Comment: No... the normal way.. clicking the edit button

Comment: Try editing this post and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time we have seen this happen is when the user accidentally clicks the back button to "edit".

This will indeed create a new duplicate-ish edited post.

Other than that we have never been able to reproduce this.